# Sending serial message in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I am trying to send this command ":01050801FF00F2" over serial in python 2.7 , with no success.
The code that i use is :

```
import serial, sys ,socket
from time import sleep
port = "COM9"
baudRate = 9600
try:
     ser = serial.Serial(port, baudRate, timeout=1)
     if not ser.isOpen():
            ser.open()
except Exception, e:
   print("Error opening com port. Quitting."+str(e))
   sys.exit(0)
print("Opening " + ser.portstr) 

#this is few ways i am trying to send with
c = '01050801FF00F2'
ser.write(c.encode('utf-8'))
sleep(3)
ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output
                 #and discard all that is in buffer
c = ':01050801FF00F2'
ser.write(c.encode('hex'))

sleep(3)
ser.write(':01050801FF00F2')
```

Comment: Can you please give add the error log that you are getting.Also have you tried using pyserial

Comment: i don't get an error , but the message isn't reached its destination so i assuming something is wrong with my code. (i assuming that because in other language (tcl) it's working) . what is pyserial?

Comment: oh my bad i havent look at the code properly that you are already using pyserial package of python.can you try adding this line at the end - ser.close().Also remove flushOutput because it is closing the connection

Comment: i used ser.close(). forgot to write it here

Comment: Also have you tried removing the flushOutput and flushInput lines from code?

Comment: yes, still not working

Comment: problem solved . not a python problem , i worked in N,8,1 and i need to work in e,7,1 . thanks

Comment: `if not ser.isOpen()` isn't necessary. If you provide the port when calling `Serial` it _is_ open. Guaranteed. Otherwise the call would raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If those are hex values, this should work:

```
c = '\x01\x05\x08\x01\xFF\x00\xF2'
ser.write(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the command using bytearray?

Perhaps you could try:

```
ser.write(b':01050801FF00F2')
```

or

```
ser.write(':01050801FF00F2'.encode())
```